# Как вставить в строку дополнительные теги?

Tags: jquery, php

Добрый день не получается символы обвернуть в теги,

имеется  строка

```
$str='49,99 грн';
```

нужно получить вид

```
49<sup>99</sup><br/><i>грн.</i>
```

Comment: Почитайте: [Функции обработки строк][1]


  [1]: http://www.php.su/functions/?cat=strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str = preg_replace("/(\d+),(\d+) грн/", "$1<sup>$2</sup><br/><i>грн.</i>", $str);
print_r($str);
```